# Visual Studio Code SSH Remote: continue running jupyter notebooks/python cells after closing the connection

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using the [Visual Studio Code SSH connection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh).
In Python, one can use a jupyter notebook `.ipynb` or cells divided by `#%%` in a `.py` file to open an interactive prompt.

I would like to close the ssh connection but keep the jupyter notebook or the interactive prompt running.

How can I do that?